# Convert Field to HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

I want to loop through the Fields of a class, like Class.getDeclaredFields()
but now I want to check if one Field is a HashMap and if so it should remove
one Value of it.
How can I reach this?
I am clueless, but trying

This is my code so far: (It makes use of the Spigot API)

```
@EventHandler
public void onInvClose(InventoryCloseEvent e) {
    Player p = (Player) e.getPlayer();

    List<RegisteredListener> listeners = HandlerList.getRegisteredListeners(Core.core);
    for(RegisteredListener l : listeners) {
        Field[] fields = l.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
        for(Field field : fields) {
            // Check if field is a HashMap
            if(field.getType().isAssignableFrom( HashMap.class )) {

                // Remove Player p from field

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#get(java.lang.Object)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Reflection get the Instance from a Field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12848479/java-reflection-get-the-instance-from-a-field)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `field.get(objectInstance)` to get particular field of particular instance and then remove specific entry from that map.

Detailed steps would be as follows:

> Step 1: Take all the declared fields by calling getDeclaredFields()
>
> Step 2: For each field returned compare the type with HashMap by using
>   equals method.
>
> Step 3: If field type matches with HashMap, then get the value by
>   calling get(objectInstace)and remove the not required value from map.

Please refer the complete example below;

```
jshell> class Player{
   ...> Object someObject;
   ...> HashMap<Integer,String> someMap;
   ...> {
   ...> someMap = new HashMap<>();
   ...> someMap.put(1,"Player");
   ...> }
   ...> }
|  modified class Player

jshell> 

jshell> 

jshell> Player player = new Player();
player ==> Player@71423665

jshell>         java.lang.reflect.Field[] fields = player.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
fields ==> Field[2] { java.lang.Object Player.someObject, ja ... l.HashMap Player.someMap }

jshell>         for(java.lang.reflect.Field field : fields) {
   ...>             // Check if field is a HashMap
   ...>             if(field.getType().equals( HashMap.class)) {
   ...> 
   ...>                 HashMap<Integer,String> data = (HashMap<Integer,String>)(field.get(player));
   ...>                 data.remove(1);
   ...>                 System.out.println("Data left in map is "+data.size());
   ...>             }
   ...>         }
Data left in map is 0
```

Comment: Could you describe the get(objectInstance) method in more detail? So I can remember it better :P

Comment: @RicheeNektar I have shared the example as well in my answer. You can call this function from field variable and pass the instance of whom you want the value to be retrieved, so in your case, __objectInstance__ will be __l__

Answer (score 1):

`var map = (Map<Player, YourValueObject>)field.get(l);` Should work and then just remove by key with p.
Though I cannot try that on my phone right now.

Comment: Unfortunately var map is not valid Java.

Comment: It did not take the ```<``` ```>``` and what´s in it without formatting finding the right type of apostrophe is not that easy on phones. xD Also ```var``` is totally a thing in Java10.

Comment: But I could try Map<?,?> :P

Comment: Ok, I have overseen the var Java 10 construct. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: If you dont have java 10 just use the same as you did in the cast in place of var.